# Problems with my tbdev code

Tags: utorrent

Hi I started tracker few days ago and i have two problems , I dont know exactly witch source code is all i know its modified tbdev I got script from a friend who went off the net some time ago...

First problem is that I am getting Error 500 on utorrent versions 2.2 and above all other versions are woking perfect....

I attached announce here

Second problem is that in my browse.php seeders/leechers are showing incorrect

[image]

I'll give example for torrent with 11 seeders and 2 leechers

[image]

And its showing only 7 seeder one of them is dupe , so its actualy 6...

My tracker is hosted on VPS , but i also have both problems on my pc using xampp

Any other file if needed please let me know so i can attach it here

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: How about posting an actual question here, rather than just a link? I recommend re-reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.

Comment: Please include the complete question within the editor, including the source code - linking to an off-site resource is not really acceptable.

Comment: @Matt It's obviously not your fault (as the PHP file originally linked to on the board this "question" pointed to can only be downloaded if you're a forum member), but this question is pretty much meaningless without the code, etc. As such, I'm going to vote to close unless the OP addresses the problems.

Comment: @midda: fine with me. I'm all out of close votes, else I would have just voted.

Comment: Sorry guys, but its my first queston. I do not know which piece of code to put because I do not know where exactly the problem, exactly on which page?
If you tell me specifically what to put, we will be much easier?  Thanks

Comment: @Kecman In an ideal world, you'd provide the most minimal code snippet that demonstrates the problem. However, this may not be feasible from what you've said. :-(

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of clients and there version that is allowed to access your site. It is (depending on the tbdev ver) in one of the folders in the include folder.

Second the problem with seeders / leechers is due to timeing.  Tbdev only updates once every 30 mins by default.  You can also change this but i would nto suggest it. it will also show ghost connections , if someone stopped seeded/leeching and then started again before the 30 min update..  I would worry about setting your access for clients first then the rest should work it self out.